# Why does Data.Dynamic contain a witness instead of a typeclass constraint?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, gadt

[`Data.Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html#t:Dynamic) has the following implementation:

```
data Dynamic where
    Dynamic :: TypeRep a -> a -> Dynamic
```

It has occurred to me that the following definition would be equivalent (at least I think):

```
data Dynamic where
    Dynamic :: Typeable a => a -> Dynamic
```

Because one can get from `TypeRep a` to a `Typeable` constraint using [`withTypeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html#v:withTypeable), and in the other direction, go from a `Typeable` constraint to `TypeRep a` using [`typeRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html#v:typeRep).

I ask this question because I often have created GADTs with typeclass constraints, often to create "existential" types, and seeing this type has made me question whether instead of using typeclass constraints I should be adding a "witness" field? What should I consider when choosing between these two approaches?

---

**Further thoughts...**

Consider something like this:

```
data SillyListA m where
  SillyListA :: Ord a => (a -> m ()) -> [a] -> SillyList m 

data SillyListB m where
  SillyListB :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> (a -> m ()) -> [a] -> SillyList m
```

Here it being explicit about the argument instead of just including the typeclass constraint has a practical purpose, because you could have different orderings on the same type, and the second definition allows that without newtype silliness.

But that just seems silly where your type is basically a singleton as is the case in `TypeRep a`.

I guess one slight benefit is that perhaps the witness can be made an argument to functions which means you don't have to use type applications to pull out the constructor.

So like with the first definition I can do:

```
f (Dynamic tr x) = ...
```

Instead of

```
f (Dynamic @a x) = ...
```

But what I find I do anyway is:

```
f (Dynamic @a _ x) = ...
```

Because the type is really handy to have in scope if `f` has any sub-functions defined that are explicitly typed, and not many functions take `TypeRep a` as an argument, they usually either require a type application or take `Proxy @a`, so I end up needing the type in scope anyway.

I have started thinking about this because I have defined the type in my own code (please shout out if I've reinvented the wheel and this exists elsewhere):

```
data DynamicF f where
  DynamicF :: forall (a :: Type) f. TypeRep a -> f a -> DynamicF f
```

And I defined it like this basically copying `Dynamic`, but I'm thinking maybe just:

```
data DynamicF f where
  DynamicF :: forall (a :: Type). Typeable a => f a -> DynamicF f
```

Is a better definition.

Comment: In newer code I would prefer the [`TypeRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html#v:TypeRep) pattern synonym for the conversion.

Comment: Ah yes, I saw that. We're on GHC 9.2 at work though so `typeRep` is what I had to use.

Comment: Some of it is probably just the state of the language when `Data.Dynamic` was written. IIRC it's older than type applications, so `f (Dynamic @a x)` wasn't an option. I think it's even older than `ScopedTypeVariables`. Back at that time, is there a good way to get a handle on the hidden type *without* a value-level witness? I'm genuinely unsure.

Comment: Sometimes you want to pattern match on the `TypeRep` directly: `f (Dynamic rep a) | App fRep aRep <- rep, Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep fRep (typeRep @[]) = ...`. It can be nice to make the representation explicit, and then present a pattern synonym (as the two are equivalent) providing the alternative interface: `pattern Dynamic' :: () => Typeable a => a -> Dynamic; pattern Dynamic' a = Dynamic TypeRep a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the answer is mostly just history. `Dynamic` is much older than `ExistentialQuantification` (GHC 6.8.1, according to the manual), which is necessary for both your modern definitions. Before this extension, you could not store a type like `a` in a datatype and you also could not store a constraint like `Typeable a` (even if it didn't mention a stored type like `a`).

E.g. inside the GHC 5.04 sources (which, even as a bzip archive, is <5MB!), I find that `Dynamic` is defined as follows

```
data Dynamic = Dynamic TypeRep Obj
data Obj = Obj
-- obviously, neither Dynamic nor Obj is exported!
```

I think it's reasonable to suggest that part of the reason `Dynamic` contains a `TypeRep` now because it's *always* held a `TypeRep`.

Since the `Dynamic` data constructor used to be non-exported, the library authors *could* have just changed it to use `Typeable` once it was made public (which happened in `base-4.10`/GHC 8.2.1) without breaking user code. But there was no strong reason to do this. Actually, there were even two weak reasons to prefer the `TypeRep` version:

- Getting `Typeable a` out of a `TypeRep a` is actually black magic, implemented by (essentially) `unsafeCoerce`ing a `Typeable a => r` into a `TypeRep a -> r`. (It is of course still *safe*, and in recent GHC the trick has apparently been codified into its own `withDict` primitive.) `TypeRep a`s are "normal" values involving fewer dark arts.
- When you're packing types up into values and moving them around it's nice to be able to actually *name* them. A `TypeRep a` is a value that you can bind with a name and can be used as a `Proxy`-esque token to represent the type `a`. (Note that many APIs don't require `Proxy a` but rather `proxy a`, where `proxy` is quantified over.) A `Typeable a` vanishes into the background the moment you get it. This is somewhat moot for `Dynamic`, since you are also getting an actual value `x :: a` (so you can do e.g. `let proxyOf :: a -> Proxy a in proxyOf x`), but it's nice to have a `TypeRep` already given. Also note that, at the time `Data.Dynamic` had its constructor exposed, type application patterns did not exist.

Both of these would have been basically just cosmetic considerations at the time and are even less important today.

Now, for writing code today, I will point out that type applications/abstractions still cannot do everything that proxies can do. The ability to name type arguments to lambdas is still missing, and thus there are situations where, for technical reasons, you *must* prefer a proxy-ish API over a type applications API.

```
class Eq a => Structure a where
    injZ :: Integer -> a
data SomeStructure where
    SomeStructure :: Structure a => SomeStructure

-- purely types-based API...
withSomeStructure :: SomeStructure -> (forall a. Structure a => r) -> r
withSomeStructure (SomeStructure @a) f = f @a
x :: SomeStructure -> Bool
x s = withSomeStructure s _can'tBindaInThisHole
-- ...doesn't work

-- proxy-based API...
withSomeStructure' :: SomeStructure -> (forall a. Structure a => Proxy a -> r) -> r
withSomeStructure' (SomeStructure @a) f = f (Proxy @a)
y :: SomeStructure -> Bool
y s = withSomeStructure' s (\a -> injZ 0 == injZ 2 `asProxyTypeOf` a)
-- ...works!
```

If you don't anticipate such a situation happening to you, or if you simply don't mind a minor inconsistency in your code, where `withSomeStructure'` gives you a `Proxy` but a hypothetical `withDynamicF` doesn't, then the `Typeable` version of `DynamicF` is fine. I personally would prefer the `TypeRep` version still.